# Symfony2, Twig: Better use block or variable?

Tags: variables, symfony, block, twig

What solution is better and recommended for short string elements? To define block and let user override it contents like:

```
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
```

or make block of variables, set their default values and let user import this block reset variable he want like:

**base template:**

```
{% block variables %}
    {% set meta.title = '' %}
{% endblock %}
<title>{{ meta.title }}</title>
```

**user template:**

```
{% block variables %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% set meta.title = 'some title' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd go with blocks. Also, remember that if you want to output contents of a block more than once, you can use the [`block`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/block.html) function:

```
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

<h1>{{ block('title') }}</h1>
```

Comment: but it won't be so easy with such tag: <link rel="author" href="{{ meta.author.url }}" title="{{ meta.author.name }}"/>

Comment: I'd say its a misuse of block if you are using it for an HTML attribute value.  IMO, block is to be used when you are using a content block (body of the page) on every page and there is a default value when one is not provided. `<title>{% block title %}Acme Toys - Store{% endblock %}</title>`.  If you are using the author link on every page, I would not use a block because it's not likely there is a single default author when a template doesn't provide one.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to call parent() after you set the variable for this to work I think.

Either way it's a personal preference, just use whatever makes your templates clearer and easier to understand.

Comment: in user template there is parent() on variables block. for me solution with variables will make code easier do maintain, as you leave default empty variables or import them and only override that you want. no problem also to set this variable value from controller. only minus is number of variables created, but blocks are also kind of variable resource.

Comment: the other problem is that I cannot call variable from parent of block in which it is defined, so that idea just will not work, need to find another way.